# How can I change the css property display to block from PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to set up some form validation for a contact us page, and I have it set up so that if there is nothing in any of the input boxes it won't send an e-mail. What I want it do is also show the hidden div I have that displays "Please fill in all boxes". This is the code I have,

```
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            document.getElementById('notValid').style.display = 'block';
        </script>
    ";
```

After that I use header to refresh the page. By default the CSS rule is that #notValid is set to display: none;  I have been doing a lot of research, and just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP, everything to do with JS. Check your console for any errors. Perhaps the JS is running before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Need to do with JS/CSS , php have no work here

Comment: I would recommend you look into ajax as this will save you moving the client from one page to another or save reloading the page to submit form data. Ajax will allow you to send form data in the background and wait for a response. As for your method of echo-ing javascript, this would all depend on where you echo this on the page. Please check your browser console for errors. If you see an error about `cannot set style property of null` then your php echo is placing the script before the page has loaded/ready. If you are interesting in ajax **-** https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Cristyan has a solution, I don't think you need to wait for DOM content to load(downloading of images and other non HTML content files), you can execute the JS as the HTML is finished loading:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.onload = function() {
          document.getElementById('notValid').style.display = 'block';
        };
      </script>";
```

Comment: Or you can assign it to `window.addEventListener("load", function` not to interfere with the load event if it's already used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the DOM is loaded

```
echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('notValid').style.display = 'block';
     });
    </script>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you're not waiting until the DOM tree is fully loaded, meaning your script executes before the element exists.

You could also use [Formazing](https://formazing.net) to do your form validation. It will automatically validate the form on the Client & Server, prevents the form submitting until the form is valid, and it will automatically create the GUI for you. And it's free for small websites.